# Findbugs plugin in sonar shows 0 bugs

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

I am trying to integrate findbugs plugin into Sonarqube. I have sucessfully installed findbugs manually.

**In root folder -> extendsion -> plugins: I have four jar files:**

sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.2

sonar-java-plugin-3.0

sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.0

sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.0

**In quality profile, I have four options:**

Findbugs,

findbugs security audit,

findBugs security minimal

and Sonar way.

**If I run sonar with Sonar way in default, sonar will show the bug, but if i set FindBugs as default, the result is 0 Bug.**

Can anyone please help me? Thank you

Comment: could you share the log of analysis ? can you precise which "bug" is shown in the interface (precise the rule key) and eventually share the piece of code where the issue is raised ? and how do you launch the analysis, maven or sonar-runner ? can you precise how you provide the bytecode to the analysis ?